# php session timer refresh while staying on same page (employment form)

Tags: php, jquery, session, session-state, session-timeout

OK, here is what I have setup.

- Basic jquery timeout check set 10 minutes before.
- PHP page that is called upon being confirmed that they want to keep
  the session open.

What I don't know how to do.

- Refresh the session time so that it won't timeout for x time. Each
  time the user states they want to keep the session open.

  ```
  session_check_timeout();
  });
   function session_timeout() {
      if (confirm('Your session will end in 10 minutes do you want to refresh your session?')) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>php/content/careers/refresh_session.php',
          success: function (data) {
              session_check_timeout();
          }
      });
  }
  }
   function session_check_timeout(){
  setTimeout(session_timeout, 5000);
  }
  ```

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Comment: you can always use cookies in combination with AJAX (to refresh the cookie time)

Comment: Added code. I am using sessions to keep this all server side.

Comment: I don't have any code in the file "refresh_session.php" yet this is the part i need help with :)!